# Why a contact form make my footer disappear?

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2, footer

I build this contact form, which works perfectly if I run it alone, but if I put on my contact page make my footer disappear, I really don't know why this is happening, I really need help with this.

**contact.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">

    <h:form id="contact">
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Nome (Obrigatório)" />
            <h:inputText id="name" value="#{contact.client.name}" />
            <h:message for="name" />

            <h:outputLabel for="email" value="E-Mail (Obrigatório)" />
            <h:inputText id="email" value="#{contact.client.email}" />
            <h:message for="email" />

            <h:outputLabel for="website" value="Website (Opcional)" />
            <h:inputText id="website" value="#{contact.client.website}" />
            <h:message for="website" />

            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:outputLabel for="text" value="Mensagem (Obrigatório):" /> <br/>
            <h:inputTextarea id="text" value="#{contact.client.text}" rows="20" cols="80" /><br/>
            <h:message for="text" />
            <br/>

            <h:commandButton value="Enviar" action="#{contact.sendMessage}"  >
                    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
            </h:commandButton>

            <h:outputText value="#{contact.messageStatus}" id="out"  />

            <a4j:status>
                <f:facet name="start">
                    <h:graphicImage name="loader.gif" library="image" />
                    <h:outputText value="Enviando ..." />
                </f:facet>
            </a4j:status>
    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

Without the componet 'contact.xhtml' it looks like:
[image: without the component]

With the component (and without the footer):
[image]

Any idea why this is happening ?
Any help ?

**UPDATE**
I host the page [here](http://50.19.242.172:8080//BrainSet/contact/contact.xhtml) guys, so you could take a look at it.

Comment: That's clearly a CSS issue. It's hard to help without knowing the generated HTML/CSS code of the page containing the contact form. I'd bet that footer's content is not properly positioned. Do you see it when you scroll the page down?

Comment: I host the page here BalusC http://50.19.242.172:8080//BrainSet/contact/contact.xhtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the HTML source of your page (rightclick page in browser, *View Source*), at the bottom I see unparsed JSF tags:

```
        <a4j:status>
        </a4j:status>
```

and then all the HTML stops there.

Apparently you forgot to declare the XML namespace for `a4j` and the HTML renderer got mad.

```
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
```

This should in development stage however have issued a clear warning. Add the following context parameter to your `web.xml` to be notified sooner on this kind of future mistakes:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: I update my web.xml, the a4j tag too, but nothing changes so far.

Comment: You did declare the `a4j` XML namespace in `contact.xhtml`? I checked your page once again, and the `<a4j:status>` is indeed still unparsed in the generated HTML source. Are you using `a4j` tags anywhere else? Do they work over there?

Comment: I re-deploy on GlassFish, please take a look now.
I use this same composition in one page alone and works fine dude.
What I noted that my <html> tag is not closed, why this is happening ?

Comment: OK, the `<a4j:status>` is rendering fine now. But the HTML renderer is been aborted somehow. This is apparently a separate problem. Does it work in local environment? Are there any exceptions/warnings in the server log?

Comment: sorry be so new with jsf dude, but where I see that ?

Comment: In local environment, it should appear in the IDE console. In production environment, it should appear in `server.log` file in `/glassfish/domains/{domainname}/logs` folder where `{domainname}` is your domain name (which defaults to `domain1` and like).

Comment: thanks by the help mate, I was able to solve my problem, it was some  HTML problem with some DIV as you said in the first comment, thanks BalusC =]

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no code to look at, I can only guess: margins of the form or the footer.